# Haskell : "lifting" a data type to a function

Tags: haskell, types, functor, lifting

Somehow, I'm still trying to build an intuition on what can I express in Haskell and what not.

I have my own (simple) matrix type and I'm wondering if it would be possible to somehow "lift" it to a function so as to make sense of the usual math notation for a matrix applied on a vector.

Let me explain this question in more detail.

```
data Matrix a = M [[a]] deriving (Show,...)

dot u v = foldr (+) 0 $ zipWith (*) u v

mv :: Num a => Matrix a -> [a] -> [a]
mv (M []) _ = []
mv _ [] = []
mv (M m) v = dot (head m) v : mv (M (tail m)) v
```

Clearly, the function `mv` implements the action of a matrix `M m` on a "vector" of type `[a]`.

But, is there a way to implement the same action with a syntax like `(M' m) v` such that

```
(M' m) v = mv (M m ) v ?
```

It should then allow to write something like

```
m = M' [[2,3],[5,7]]
v = m [1,0] -- v == [2,5]
```

I suspect the matrix data type I defined isn't enough to do such a lifting. Somehow I think I'm trying to find a functor from a self-defined matrix type to some `hom([a],[a])`, i.e., the set of morphisms  in category of vector spaces `Vec`, but my data type lacks the necessary structure.

Is there a fundamental reason why it might not be possible to do such "lifting"?

Comment: One idea is to make `Matrix` something like a [difference list](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/dlist-0.7.1.2/docs/Data-DList.html); instead of it being a nested list, it's a function that takes a nested list and a list and returns another list. That is, you could think of `M [[2,3],[5,7]]` as a partially applied function rather than just a wrapped nested list. `mv` would then be more of a smart constructor.

Comment: Notice that if you define `m = mv $ M [[2,3], [5,7]]` then you get that m [1, 0] gets your desired effect. This is just a play on currying: a partial evaluation of your mv function.

Comment: Seeing this just now. Yes, I've been playing with currying so far as you mention. The problem comes when I then try to calculate the gradient/jacobian of an expresion with respect to the matrix values. It ran into new compilation erros when I tried that. For instance, let say you have a simklple, multilayer feedforward neural network. introducing ```mv```  runs into problems with automatic differentiation. Not sure if I should detail this case in my original question too. It might provide other useful answers too...

Comment: @Julián, thanks for your comments. I realize now I may not be asking the right question for the problem I have. I will thus likely delete this question and post another, more focused one.

Comment: @chepner, thanks for your comments. I don't quite get how to use a Difference list, but I think I first need to rethink my own question. See my previous comment.

Comment: @MASL: please post the code, I don't mind looking at it, but I can't answer on nothing

Comment: @Julián Thanks. I posted a new, more specific question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37088840/automatic-differentiation-ad-with-respect-to-list-of-matrices-in-haskell