# Automatic differentiation (AD) with respect to list of matrices in Haskell

Tags: haskell, matrix, nonlinear-optimization, automatic-differentiation

I am trying to understand how can I use `Numeric.AD` (automatic differentiation) in Haskell.

I defined a simple matrix type and a scalar function taking an array and two matrices as arguments. I want to use AD to get the gradient of the scoring function with respect to both matrices, but I'm running into compilation problems. Here is the code

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveTraversable, DeriveFunctor, DeriveFoldable #-}
import Numeric.AD.Mode.Reverse as R
import Data.Traversable as T
import Data.Foldable as F

--- Non-linear function on "vectors"
logistic x = 1.0 / (1.0 + exp(-x) )
phi v = map logistic v
phi' (x:xs) = x : (phi xs)

--- dot product
dot u v = foldr (+) 0 $ zipWith (*) u v

--- simple matrix type
data Matrix a = M [[a]] deriving (Eq,Show,Functor,F.Foldable,T.Traversable)

--- action of a matrix on a vector
mv _ [] = []
mv (M []) _ = []
mv ( M m ) v = ( dot (head m)  v ) :  (mv (M (tail m)) v )

--- two matrices
mbW1 = M $ [[1,0,0],[-1,5,1],[1,2,-3]]
mbW2 = M $ [[0,0,0],[1,3,-1],[-2,4,6]]

--- two different scoring functions
sc1 v m = foldr (+) 0 $ (phi' . (mv m) )  v  

sc2 :: Floating a => [a] -> [Matrix a] -> a
sc2 v [m1, m2] = foldr (+) 0 $ (phi' . (mv m2) . phi' . (mv m1) ) v

strToInt = read :: String -> Double
strLToIntL = map strToInt
--- testing
main = do
        putStrLn $ "mbW1:" ++ (show mbW1)
        putStrLn $ "mbW2:" ++ (show mbW2)
        rawInput <-  readFile "/dev/stdin"
        let xin= strLToIntL $ lines rawInput
        putStrLn "sc xin mbW1"
        print $ sc1 xin mbW1  --- ok. = 
        putStrLn "grad (sc1 xin) mbW1"
        print $ grad ( sc1 xin) mbW1   -- yields an error: expects xin [Reverse s Double] instead of [Double]
        putStrLn "grad (sc1 [3,5,7]) mbW1"
        print $ grad ( sc1 [3,5,7]) mbW1   --- ok. =
        putStrLn "sc2 xin [mbW1,mbW2]"
        print $ sc2 xin [mbW1, mbW2]
        putStrLn "grad (sc2 [3,5,7) [mbW1,mbW2]"
        print $ grad ( sc2 [3,5,7]) [mbW1, mbW2]  --- Error: see text
```

The last line (grad on sc2) gives the following error:

```
Couldn't match type ‘Reverse s (Matrix Double)’
               with ‘Matrix (Reverse s (Matrix Double))’
Expected type: [Reverse s (Matrix Double)]
               -> Reverse s (Matrix Double)
  Actual type: [Matrix (Reverse s (Matrix Double))]
               -> Reverse s (Matrix Double)
In the first argument of ‘grad’, namely ‘(sc2 [3, 5, 7])’
In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
  ‘grad (sc2 [3, 5, 7]) [mbW1, mbW2]’
```

I don't understand where the "Matrix of Matrix" in the actual type seen comes from. I'm feeding the `grad` with a curried version of sc2, making it a function on a list of Matrix.

Commenting out the two offending lines runs without problem, i.e., the first gradient works and is correctly calculated (I'm feeding [1,2,3] as input to the program):

```
mbW1:M [[1.0,0.0,0.0],[-1.0,5.0,1.0],[1.0,2.0,-3.0]]
mbW2:M [[0.0,0.0,0.0],[1.0,3.0,-1.0],[-2.0,4.0,6.0]]
sc1 xin mbW1
1
2
3
2.0179800657874893
grad (sc1 [3,5,7]) mbW1
M [[3.0,5.0,7.0],[7.630996942126885e-13,1.2718328236878141e-12,1.7805659531629398e-12],[1.0057130122694228e-3,1.6761883537823711e-3,2.3466636952953197e-3]]
sc2 xin [mbW1,mbW2]
1.8733609463863194
```

Both errors are an issue. I want to take the gradient of any such `sc2` scoring function, depending on an array of matrices, evaluated at any given "point" xin. Clearly, I'm not yet understanding the AD library well enough. Any help would be appreciated.